# Is there is the way to skip ansible list parameter if provided list is empty?

Tags: list, ansible

I'm trying to use ansible to run docker, one of parameters is `ports` which is a list. Is there a way to NOT SET IT UP if provided list is empty? I know that I can separate it based on when parameter, but my target is to have single common step for that: `default(omit)` works for dictionary, not for list

```yaml
- name: Redeploy {{ service.name }} container
  docker_container:
      name: "{{ sservice.name }}"
      image: "{{ service.image['name'] }}:{{ service.image['version'] }}"
      state: stopped
      networks:
        - name: "{{ docker_network }}"
      env: "{{ sservice.config['environment'] | default(omit) }}"
      ports: "{{ service.config['ports'] | default(omit) }}"
      log_driver: "json-file"
      log_options:
          max-size: "10m"
      pull: false
      recreate: yes
      restart_policy: always
```

Comment: `default(omit) works for dictionary, not for list` <= this is entirely false and I actually [cannot reproduce your problem](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/aa7d42c051a8cc5f854497a109628f2e)

Comment: @Zeitounator indeed you are correct, when the `ports` variable is NOT set value is omitted, I had an error because I was passing an empty list which leads to an error when value is not set it is working as expected.

Comment: `default` has a second parameter to behave the same way for an undefined or empty/false value for that var. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values => `default(omit, true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that in my configuration I was passing an empty list to `docker_container` module what leaded to en error `FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Invalid port: \"\""}`

When `ports` is not set, the value is omitted as expected. Kudos to @Zeitounator !

Answer (score -2):

You can add a [when conditional](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when) to the task with the jinja2 filter [count/length](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.length) :

```
when: service.config['ports'] | count > 0
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question as: 1) he exactly said in his post that he did not want this solution 2) it's entirely possible to omit the option in the task.